# Is .finally in the ES6 specification?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

a lot of Promise libraries, like Q or Bluebird, implents a method called `.finally` that is triggered on both success and error.

Is this method present also in the ES6 promise? I can't find it out. Seems not to be present in Babel (6to5).

Any help in clarifing this is higly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Nope. ES doesn't have `finally`

Comment: `.then()` will be called on `resolve()` or `reject()`, and if anywhere in the promise chain something throws, `.catch()` will be fired https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: "*I can't find it out.*" - why not? Just [look it up](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-properties-of-the-promise-prototype-object)!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 is not finalized yet. It is in draft status. The current draft doesn't have a `finally` method.